# numpy: print array with indentation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to print `numpy` `array` with indentation for debugging.

Say I have an `array` `a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])`, then simple `print(a)` will give

```
[[ 63 903 942 952]
 [185 332 511 893]]
```

Now if I put in `\t` in `print("\t" + str(a))`, then I get

```
    [[ 63 903 942 952]
 [185 332 511 893]]
```

while I want to have

```
    [[ 63 903 942 952]
     [185 332 511 893]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print("\t" + str(a).replace('\n','\n\t'))
        [[1 2 3 4]
         [5 6 7 8]]
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do it :

```
print('\t' + str(a).replace('\n', '\n\t'))
```